# In ZSH @ symbol appears during autocompletion of cd command

Tags: gnome-terminal, zsh

I use ZSH and after I type cd command and press Tab I get '@' symbol after some particular entries[image]

Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're seeing is the effect of the `LIST_TYPES` shell option. From the `Completion` section of `man zshoptions`:

```
    LIST_TYPES (-X) <D>
          When  listing files that are possible completions, show the type
          of each file with a trailing identifying mark.
```

The "trailing identifying mark" appears to follow the same convention as the `-F` option of `ls` (aka `--classify` in GNU `ls`) i.e. `@` indicates that the completion is a symbolic link.

You'll find it also happens by default in completion listings in the `tcsh` shell from which `zsh` borrowed a few interactive features.

You can turn off this behavior using `unsetopt list_types` or `set +o list_types` if you prefer the standard way to turn options on/off.